# Erro na Instalação do MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

Devido ao um problema no meu SO ontem, acabei formatando meu PC, e quando fui instalar o mysql-server, baixou a versão 8 como default pelo apt-get, estando tudo ajeitado, fui usar e quando tento executar qualquer query em qualquer tabela ele me retorna esse erro.

```
The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

Procurei mil soluções, a maioria fala que fizeram upgrade do 5.7 para o 8, mas no meu caso foi só a instalação. E não tem jeito do meu Banco funcionar.

mysql_upgrade diz que está obsoleto. Alguém me da um help

Comment: Também já tive muitos problemas com o MySQL 8, mas não esse, especificamente. Recomendo tentar instalar o MariaDB no lugar, que funciona basicamente da mesma forma que o 5.7, sem as modificações pesadas que a Oracle fez nas versões mais recentes.

Comment: Pensei nisso, acabei não fazendo só por preguiça mesmo, vou instalar e ver no que da.